# AzureDevOps Credentials Visual Studio MAC

Tags: macos, visual-studio, oauth-2.0, macos-catalina

I just updated to MacOS Catalina because a Xamarin project needed the latest XCode.  Everything was working **before** this update.

I am now unable to push to or pull from AzureDevops ({domain}.visualstuido.com), though I can clone a project from it without any problems.

When attempting to push or pull (even a project just cloned) I get the Microsoft sign-in dialog but it's blank (see image below).

I have tried rebooting (several times), restarting Visual Studio, applied all updates, (VS, MacOS, Java etc) but nothing is making any difference. Despite Googling this for several hours I can't any cause/resolution.

[image]

I'm looking for help on how to diagnose the cause and of course fix the problem.